# How can I call a C++ method from react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native

I want to add a C++ file and call its methods from react-native repository.
I have already tried some of the answers which says to install **ffi-napi** but that is not working. There are some specific tools requirement for this dependency.

So is there a way I can call the C++ methods without installing any dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I have had success with Marius' way of doing it. Its not too simple, but it works well IMO.

https://reime005.medium.com/react-native-and-c-87a2311dc3d